# How can i fix intelliJ Spring red text error?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEcIt.png)

There is any error. It works well. But intelliJ show me red text on files. How can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like VCS (git, subversion, etc) is configured in the project, but these files are excluded from it.
That's why they are [marked red](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html).

To add files to version control, choose the **Add** action in the **Git** submenu of the file context menu:
[image: Add to version control action]